# udf excel 2007 and possibly global

Tags: excel

Would appreciate a little help if possible please.

I was trying to help a colleague in work collating some data.
The sheet is a copy of all bank statements including name address and other irrelevant data (to us).

The data he required all had a valid date in column B, so I created a udf as below

```
Public Function IsADate(rngCell As Range) As Boolean
If IsDate(rngCell) Then
    IsADate = True
Else
    IsADate = False
End If

End Function
```

to use the Isdate VBA function.

It worked great.

Just before finishing time he came over and told me it no longer worked on another sheet in the same workbook.

I checked, the function was still in a module in that workbook, and if you keyed it in on a sheet, it came up in the list of functions presented, yet after completing the formula the cell contains #NAME.   In the little time possible I was unable to find the cause.

Does anyone have an idea what has gone wrong. He did rename the workbook, but is using the same workbook.

As an aside, I tried to make the function global in my setup by

**a**. Putting it in Personal.xlsm where I have various macros I use in all my workbooks

**b**. As an addin, saving as a .xla and .xlam file, and selecting the file in addins

It was still not recognised, did not even come up on the function list.

I've come home and tried option b in Excel 2003 (which is all I have) and it works fine in another workbook.

Puzzled to say the least. :D

TIA

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion. `IsDate(RngCell)` returns a `true` or `false` so there is no need to wrap it in an `if` statement.

Comment: At first, Check the name of your UDF is exactly what is being typed in the formula bar. If problem persists, then there are other ways to try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on not having to use the If statement

Comment: ZAT, it is exactly the same. On the PC that it was working on it comes up in the list of functions as you type the name. However the macro is batter as it took ages putting the function into all the cells to filter on. It was meant to be a quick fix to help out a colleague.

Answer (score 0):

`#NAME` indicates a naming conflict or a missing name.  Excel shares a name space with all open workbooks, so if you had two workbooks open with the same function name or the same function was declared as public in multiple modules or in a Worksheet object and a module it would create a naming conflict.

Comment: That might be the cause. If I have time (targets to meet :D) I will try and investigate that theory. Also good to know in case I create any more. Thank you.